# linux c/c++ preg_replace type of function?

Tags: c++, linux, preg-replace

I'm trying to figure out an preg_replace() (php) style function that I can use in c++ (linux).

Can someone help me translate this?

```
$str = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'),array('-',''),$str);
```

Comment: I removed the C tag, as you are writing in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boost::regex library

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Best option would be to link with the [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://www.pcre.org/) (PCRE) library and use the functions it provides.

You can check `pcrecpp(3)` for more info. A sample code would be:

```cpp
#include <pcrecpp.h>

pcrecpp::RE("\s+").Replace("-", &s); // where s is the target string
pcrecpp::RE("[^A-Za-z0-9\-]").Replace("", &s);
```